# Is not having a modular multiplicative inverse, the same thing as linear dependence in a vector of size 2x1?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

It seems to me that for two numbers not having a modular multiplicative inverse and linear dependence in a 2x1 / 1x2 vector is related, is there a well known theorem / lemma on the relation between the two concepts?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on how you think they're related?

Comment: Something to do with gcd of two numbers being one and the ability to use linear combinations of them, I'm not a mathematician so I might be missing something